Spyder Not Able to Use Tkinter
I am trying to create a Python program that uses Tkinter. I have installed Tkinter using Homebrew and did not have any errors. However, when I open Spyder and try to run it in there I get the following error:
TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /opt/homebrew/opt/tcl-tk/lib/tcl8.6 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/library /Applications/Spyder.app/library /Applications/Spyder.app/tcl8.6.12/library /Applications/tcl8.6.12/library

/opt/homebrew/opt/tcl-tk/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.12, need exactly 8.6.14
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.12, need exactly 8.6.14
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.6.14"
    (file "/opt/homebrew/opt/tcl-tk/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source /opt/homebrew/opt/tcl-tk/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

What is weird is if I open Spyder in terminal it runs properly without the error. I am just trying to test with a simple program before doing anything advanced. I have looked online and used A.I. to try and find this answer but nothing helps. Here is the code if it matters:
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Hello World")
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World")
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Also everything is updated. I just installed the newest version of Spyder today and also verified that Python, Pip, and Homebrew were current. Additionally, I made sure the environment variables in the terminal shell were updated too. I think though that if this weren't the case I couldn't get it to work if I loaded via terminal but it isn't the case.
